Managing Error Messages and Codes in Large Spring Boot Applications
How do large-scale applications systematically set up error messages with corresponding codes for all their APIs using Spring Boot and Java, especially when they have over 100 different error messages aligned with HTTP status codes?
Instead of handling every exception in every API method, is there a more general approach like @ControllerAdvice? What are the drawbacks of using @ControllerAdvice, especially concerning the order of exception handlers?
@GetMapping("/user/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<UserResponse> getUserById(@PathVariable String id) {
        List<UserInfo> userInfoByIdList = null;
        try {
            userInfoByIdList = userService.getUserById(id);
            if (userInfoByIdList.isEmpty()) {
                throw new NoUserFoundException("No user found with ID: " + id);
            }
            if (userInfoByIdList.get(0).isDeleted()) {
                throw new UserDeletedException("User with ID: " + id + " has been deleted");
            }
            if (!userService.isUserEligible(userInfoByIdList.get(0))) {
                throw new UserNotEligibleForAccessingUserException("User with ID: " + id + " is not eligible for access");
            }
        } catch (NoUserFoundException e) {
            log.error("NoUserFoundException while fetching user for ID {}: {}", id, e.getMessage(), e);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new UserResponse(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value(), e.getMessage()), 
                                        HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        } catch (UserDeletedException e) {
            log.error("UserDeletedException while fetching user for ID {}: {}", id, e.getMessage(), e);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new UserResponse(HttpStatus.GONE.value(), e.getMessage()), 
                                        HttpStatus.GONE);
        } catch (UserNotEligibleForAccessingUserException e) {
            log.error("UserNotEligibleForAccessingUserException while fetching user for ID {}: {}", id, e.getMessage(), e);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new UserResponse(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value(), e.getMessage()), 
                                        HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            log.error("ServiceException while fetching user for ID {}: {}", id, e.getMessage(), e);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new UserResponse(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value(), e.getMessage()), 
                                        HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error while fetching user for ID {}: {}", id, e.getMessage(), e);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new UserResponse(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value(), e.getMessage()), 
                                        HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(new UserResponse(HttpStatus.OK.value(), userInfoByIdList), HttpStatus.OK);
    }


This feels like a looking for advice or recommendation rather than a specific coding problem and therefore feels off topic. @ControllerAdvice is the standard way of handling exceptions as well as HandlerExceptionResolver - you can read more about these for example here. Analyzing drawbacks/advantages of each approach should be done by you, in general in software development you implement one approach and adjust/change if necessary.

@ControllerAdvice is the way to go most of the time because of the centralized error handling and cleaness of the code. In your case it would look something like this:
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(NoUserFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleNoUserFoundException(NoUserFoundException ex, WebRequest request) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value(), ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(UserDeletedException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleUserDeletedException(UserDeletedException ex, WebRequest request) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.GONE.value(), ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.GONE);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(UserNotEligibleForAccessingUserException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleUserNotEligibleForAccessingUserException(UserNotEligibleForAccessingUserException ex, WebRequest request) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value(), ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ServiceException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleServiceException(ServiceException ex, WebRequest request) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value(), ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleGlobalException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value(), ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}

but as mentioned above this is more of an advice question instead of a technical one.
